# Ubuntu armhf 404 packages! Please help! Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, android, software-sources, arm

Ok so here is every error that I get during sudo apt-get update or any sudo apt-get operation

BEFORE YOU LEAVE PLEASE READ! (thank you ^^)

(Remembered to add this after finishing the text:
 I'm using ubuntu 13.04 by the way!)

I do not know how to create a sploiler so the code or the whole terminal will be provided in the end. I will just explain my situation.
So I tried to get Ubuntu (and because I was desperate I tried any distro that was available(debian)) or just linux to work, I ended up getting Ubuntu to work, *it was a glorious moment!* But the glorious moment quickly vanished away as the most practical use also fades away, yes, I am talking about the `Sudo apt-get` command or operation.

My android phone is a samsung galaxy s4, some specs are provided:

```
Model : "APQ8064T"
Cores : "4"
Architecture : "Krait 300"
Revision : "r1p0"
Process : "28nm"
Clock Speed : "384 MHZ - 1.89 GHz" #Pretty much a fast phone!
GPU Vendor : "Qualcomm"
GPU Renderer : "Adreno (TM) 320 @ 450 MHz"
Scaling Governor : Currently set to "ondemand"
```

So I mean the phone could easily run android and ubuntu at the same time.

Now, the way I did this was following a tutorial which is : [HERE](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2381181)

I followed the steps, I did it the "vnc" method, where you basically run Ubuntu in Text Mode on an ADB SHELL; or TERMINAL EMULATOR; and allow vnc connections to it. I pretty much don't use it as the connection is slow, but it is broken anyways. You need a .img file for the use of it. It uses busybox to mount a loop devices or some thing like that and VOILA just like magic, it runs perfectly! ... Or so I thought, anyway from what I can see is that it runs using armhf, my phone is using

```
Kernel Architecture : "armv7l"
```

So I'm guessing it means what architecture It is using.
It does over heat quiet a bit (47c) but it only uses two cores at medium to high usage (that's 918 MHz and 1350 respectively!)

Here is some of that text below, I already tried to edit the sources.list but it didn't work, I removed the "port.ubuntu", changed it to "release.ubuntu" and also "old-release.ubuntu" nothing seems to work.

Now here is those 404 errors:

```
root@jflte:/ # sh /sdcard/ubuntu.sh                                            
Making mount points and mounting to them...
Connecting to /sdcard...
Putting in some settings...
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
ubuntu is configured with SSH and VNC servers that can be accessed from the IP:
(You will see an error about wlan0 if your WiFi is disabled. Safe to ignore.)
-----------------  OKAY, starting Ubuntu!  -----------------
Start VNC server? (y/n)
y
Start SSH server? (y/n)
y
Now enter the screen size you want in pixels (e.g. 800x480), followed by [ENTER]:
1920x1080

New 'X' desktop is localhost:0

Starting applications specified in /home/ubuntu/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /home/ubuntu/.vnc/localhost:0.log


If you see the message 'New 'X' Desktop is localhost:0' then you are ready to VNC    into your ubuntu OS..

If connection from a different machine on the same network as the android device use the address below:
192.168.0.87

If using androidVNC, change the 'Color Format' setting to 24-bit colour, and once    you've VNC'd in, change the 'input mode' to touchpad (in settings)
 * Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server sshd                             [ OK ] 
Save settings as defaults? (y/n) (You can always change it later in the app)
n

To shut down the Linux environment, just enter 'exit' at this terminal - and WAIT for all shutdown routines to finish!

root@localhost:/# sudo apt-get update
Ign http://releases.ubuntu.com raring Release.gpg
Ign http://releases.ubuntu.com raring Release
Err http://releases.ubuntu.com raring/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.148 80]
Err http://releases.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.148 80]
Err http://releases.ubuntu.com raring/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.148 80]
Err http://releases.ubuntu.com raring/main armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.148 80]
Err http://releases.ubuntu.com raring/restricted armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.148 80]
Err http://releases.ubuntu.com raring/universe armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.148 80]
Ign http://releases.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en
Ign http://releases.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://releases.ubuntu.com raring/universe Translation-en
W: Failed to fetch http://releases.ubuntu.com/dists/raring/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.148 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://releases.ubuntu.com/dists/raring/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.148 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://releases.ubuntu.com/dists/raring/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.148 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://releases.ubuntu.com/dists/raring/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.148 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://releases.ubuntu.com/dists/raring/restricted/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.148 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://releases.ubuntu.com/dists/raring/universe/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.148 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
root@localhost:/#
```

So It is the sources.list file, please help! I can't wait to get this working :)
I have already come so far...

Comment: Can't be, I already tried it and it didn't work...

Comment: [Terminal Image](http://i.imgur.com/n0ZdoRM.png)

[Gedit Image](http://i.imgur.com/Hq5dgyl.png)

Comment: @muru Thank you, with your help, I managed to dig deeper, until I found myself [HERE](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades) And basically replaced it with the codename which was I believe raring! I am very happy. :D

Answer (score 2):

Anyway I found a fix after digging deeper...

I found this website [EOLUpgrades](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades)

Which helped me. I just did a `sudo apt-get update` only received one 404 because I included an optional source

Here is my sources.list

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-backports main restricted universe multivers
```

The last one will be removed. The upgrade is still going, and installing...

For anyone receiving this just add in the sources.list and removed the last line to get

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

Update finished.
Installing java.

So I will close this now. Thank you muru, as your encouraged me to dig a little deeper. :D